# How to register SIP Client with Asterisk PBX through java

Tags: java, asterisk

I have done example programs prescribed in http://www.asterisk-java.org/development/tutorial.html successfully. Now I would like to register SIP client by passing their extension's credentials like extension ID, secret, domain and so on. How we can do these tasks by using Asterisk java? Or do we need another framework like SIP Client lib to establish connection between client and asterisk?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use sip.conf or [asterisk realtime](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+RealTime) for that.

I highly recommend you read any book, for example ORelly's "Asterisk the future of telephony"

No, it is absolutely not possible to do authorization via java in current Asterisk.

If you mean you need a java UA, you can use iax-java library or any sip library for java.

Comment: Thanks @arheops...In many tutorial I have covered, they propose JAIN SIP lib is convenient to make softphone. Do You have any idea about this?

Comment: I think it is bad idea do softphone yourself if you have questions like you ask. Get opensource one and extend.

Comment: Can you suggest best Softphone available in opensource comfortable with asterisk? If you can please give references that provide adequate  knowledge about extending softphone

Comment: Suggestion of tool is offtopic on stack overflow. Please be sure you have read rules.

Comment: Asterisk AMI and AGI script are feasible to create sip client, they should be vigilant about happenings in asterisk server. Are they?